# Google app engine php executable path not found

Tags: php, google-app-engine, installation

Followed the steps given on the official google app engine page for installing the sdk for php->

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld

but I get this error in my browser on opening localhost.

```
The path specified with the --php_executable_path flag () does not exist.
```

How to set it ?
Installed on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When starting dev appserver via the script one can pass in `--php_executable_path` pointing to the location of your php executable. The reason for the error is that it was unable to find php looking in the path and such. See [documentation for example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver#PHP_Running_a_custom_php_install).

```
$ google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/opt/local/bin/php-cgi54 path/to/your/app
```

Answer (score 1):

Install php5-cgi:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

Run app:

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi path/to/your/app
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: On linux use

`sudo apt-get install php-cgi
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi app.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

On windows:

Download php at here https://www.php.net/downloads.php 
Example the path for download  D:\php72

Run app:

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path="D:\php72\php-cgi.exe" path_app/app.yaml
```