# Google AppEngine - The PHP runtime is not avaliable

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I follow this link :
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#creating_a_simple_request_handler

I downloaded sdk and create helloworld folder and contains. Then i run this code :

```
/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py /helloworld
```

***Then output is :***

INFO     2015-12-30 08:10:02,546 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking  for updates to the SDK.

INFO     2015-12-30 08:10:02,722 sdk_update_checker.py:257] The SDK is up to date.

WARNING  2015-12-30 08:10:02,749 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.helloworld.root/search_indexes

INFO     2015-12-30 08:10:02,752 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55572

INFO     2015-12-30 08:10:02,754 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080

INFO     2015-12-30 08:10:02,755 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000

ERROR    2015-12-30 08:10:03,757 php_runtime.py:348] The PHP runtime is not available

Traceback (most recent call last):

File"/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py",
 line 344, in new_instance self._check_binaries(php_executable_path, gae_extension_path)

File"/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py",
 line 265, in _check_binaries raise _PHPBinaryError('The development server must be started with the 'PHPBinaryError: The development server must be started with the --php_executable_path flag set to the path of the php-cgi binary.

Comment: So what happens if you DO follow the clear instructions in the last message, and add to your command line running dev_appserver.py the `--php_executable_path` flag followed by the path to the php-cgi binary?

Comment: is your helloworld directory located directly in `/`?  if not you may have a typo in the argument of the `dev_apserver. py` cmd,  in the tutorial the `/` is at the end...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google app engine php executable path not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618871/google-app-engine-php-executable-path-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

passing `--skip_sdk_update_check=true` and `--php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi` might be required. despite the screenshot reads "App Engine **for** PHP", it's the [python-appengine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-appengine) utilizing one [PHP-CGI](http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.php) executable.

[image: Run/Debug Configuration]

the launch command (PHP 7.0 locally):

```
/usr/bin/python /usr/lib64/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_remote_debugging=yes --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8081 --skip_sdk_update_check=true --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi
```